# pandas groupby count co-existances

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I want to get the countries affinities by products.
I have such a df:

```
   cntr  prod
0  fr    cheese
1  ger   potato
2  it    cheese
3  it    tomato
4  fr    wine
5  it    wine
6  ger   cabbage
7  fr    cabbage
```

I was trying to get a co-existence matrix of number of products, which would tell me the countries affinities, as such:

```
    fr   ger  it
fr       1    2
ger 1         0
it  2    0
```

my test was first to proceed to do a cross groupby trying to add a 3rd dimension so to get

```
fr   fr
     ger  1
     it   2
ger  fr   1
     ger
     it   0
it   fr   2
     ger  0
     it
```

this is what I tryied, but it is failing to add the second layer..
any suggestion?

Comment: What are diagonal values ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need `merge` for cross join with `crosstab` and if necessary set diagonal to `NaN` by [`numpy.fill_diagonal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html):

```
df = pd.merge(df, df, on='prod')
df = pd.crosstab(df['cntr_x'], df['cntr_y']).astype(float)
np.fill_diagonal(df.values, np.nan)
print (df)
cntr_y   fr  ger   it
cntr_x               
fr      NaN  1.0  2.0
ger     1.0  NaN  0.0
it      2.0  0.0  NaN
```

Comment: this is just the thing jezrael, thank you so much. diagonal I don't really care since I want to check on each other, not itself. I started to feel crosstab could be helpful but I was stuck with groupby. thank you!